# What does どころか mean here?

Tags: grammar, particles, syntax, conjunctions

This is the prologue to a video game. Below are the official subtitles in the NTSC-U release.

> と言っても、これを信じている学者は、世界で数人しかいないんだが。
> *"However, there are only a few scholars in the world who believe this."*
>
> その一人が先生ってわけですね？
> *Clair: "You must be one of those scholars then, professor."*
>
> 少数派どころか、学説扱いされていない。
> *Koji: "Actually, this idea is not even accepted as theory."*

Running the last sentence through google translate **without** 少数派どころか、gives:

> 学説扱いされていない。- It is not treated as theory.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3153/9831 or https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/7081/9831 or https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5180/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"AどころかB" has two different usages:

1. Quite contrary to A, (the fact is) B; Far from A, (it's) B
   <sub>(B is the opposite of A)</sub>

   > - その本は安いどころか、3万円もした。
   > - 彼は英語が苦手どころか、英語の弁論大会で優勝経験がある。
   > - 詳しく知っているどころか、名前を聞いたことすらない。
2. Not (just) A but even B; Even A is an understatement, (the fact is) B
   <sub>(B is an extreme version of A)</sub>

   > - その本は安いどころか、たったの1円だった。
   > - 彼は英語が苦手どころか、アルファベットすら書けない。
   > - 詳しく知らないどころか、名前を聞いたことすらない。
   > - 詳しく知っているどころか、その人は私の妻ですよ。

Either way, B has to be something surprising.

As you can see in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3153/5010), the "traditional" usage is 1. Some learning resources mention only the first usage. However, the second usage is not uncommon, and at least [this page](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/05/28/jlptn2-grammar-dokoroka/) and [this page](https://hedgehog-japanese.com/grammar/jlpt-n2/dokoroka/) explain both usages.

In your example, the second usage is intended. Being 少数派 is already bad, but the fact (学説扱いされていない) is even worse.

> 少数派どころか、学説扱いされていない。
> Calling it a minority opinion is not enough; it's not even recognized as a theory.